# How can I remove a laminate floor plank from underneath a door jamb?

Tags: laminate-floor

When removing laminate flooring, is it possible to remove a laminate floor plank from underneath a door jamb without damaging the plank? What is the best way to begin removal when the plank runs across the doorway and is tucked underneath the door jamb?

[image]

Comment: A picture would help.

Comment: Yes, it really depends on the situation.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to remove the plank in a non-destructive way? Usually, you either need something to stay or be gone.

Comment: Pull the trim off the door and make a notch (that you won't see once you put that back) around the case. Remove the floor trim, then it can be angled out of its grove. As far as damaging it... YMWV. - It's a lot of work... for why? (have to pull half of the other door's trim off too)